# Is it possible to construct this triangle?

Tags: geometry

Triangle has sides a,b,c and corresponding angles A,B,C. Given: lengths of a and b, and an angle whose measure is A-B. Is it possible to construct this triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are infinitely many incongruent such triangles, even when $a=b$ (and therefore $A-B=0$).